# Adding a gcc plugin to a cmake project

Tags: gcc, build, cmake, dependencies, gcc-plugins

I want to add a gcc plugin to my cmake project. The solution should satisfy the following:

- The gcc plugin should be pulled from a git repository (I can use external project for this)
- Everything that is not the gcc plugin should **automatically** order-depend on the gcc plugin. This means that if the plugin is not built, it is built before anything else.
- OPTIONAL: Everything should **automatically** fully-depend on the gcc plugin. This means that if the plugin got updated, then it and everything else will be rebuilt.

Note that by **automatically** I mean that I don't have to manually add this dependency for every target.

How can I implement this with cmake?

Comment: Have you tried anything? 1. `ExternalProject_Add(GCCPlugin ...)`. 2. `add_dependencies(<other-target> GCCPlugin)`. 3. Automatically because of second step.

Comment: How do I cause the second step to happen automatically for all other targets?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no direct way for add one target as dependent for all-other-targets. If it is your actual problem, edit the question correspondignly. Currently your question is read as "write-code-for-me".